# Unable to install NODE-SCSS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sass

I am facing the following error while installing node-scss module
`npm version:6.13.4`
`node version:v12.16.1`
The error message reflects: Failed at the node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall script.
Is there issue with my node version
i tried installing the latest version of node but installed te node-scss module but faced the same problem again

````
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\Coursera\\Bootstrap4\\conFusion\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\Coursera\\Bootstrap4\\conFusion\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\Coursera\\Bootstrap4\\conFusion\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\Coursera\\Bootstrap4\\conFusion\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\Coursera\\Bootstrap4\\conFusion\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\Coursera\\Bootstrap4\\conFusion\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\Coursera\\Bootstrap4\\conFusion\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN confusion@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-17T13_01_25_173Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: And you don’t think it’s a Python issue?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/JeremyEnglert/JointsWP/issues/317

Comment: did you follow the node gyp setup instruction on their github page? https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/README.md#on-windows

Comment: `python2 Error: not found: python2`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

1. Delete package-lock.json,
2. Delete node_modules folder,
3. Run `npm install` again.

Done